# SQL count of instances and last occurrence by ID

Tags: sql

I have a table 'exports' which looks like the following:

Answer (score 1):

If you only wanted to select the most recent row, you could try:

```
SELECT *
FROM exports
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, design_category 
     ORDER BY timestamp DESC) = 1
```

However it looks like you also want to aggregate.

You could combine your aggregate with "last known value" with something like this:

```
SELECT
 user_id,
 LAST_VALUE('timestamp' ignore NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS LATEST_EXPORT_DATE, 
 LAST_VALUE(design_category ignore NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS LATEST_DESIGN,
COUNT(1) AS count_events
FROM exports
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Edit: The syntax might be different depending on your RDBMS. I got this syntax from [Rasgo](https://docs.rasgoml.com/rasgo-docs/transforms/all-transforms) which automatically translates into SQL for you. I used snowflake syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I like @Josh answer but you could also use windowing functions.
here is the fiddle   https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/44CMtdjjir4FwtF2y4TXf2/0

```
with t as (
  select 
    *, 
    RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY user_id 
      ORDER BY 
        timestamp DESC
    ) rnk, 
    count('Dracula') over (partition by user_id) as count_events 
  from 
    exported
) 
select 
  user_id, 
  count_events, 
  design_category, 
  timestamp 
from 
  t 
where 
  rnk = 1 
order by 
  user_id desc;
```

Comment: @Spatial_Tx I updated the fiddle to include the percent.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/44CMtdjjir4FwtF2y4TXf2/1